# How to get an image from ImageView with applied effects

Tags: java, image, javafx

I have a custom ImageChanger class extending ImageView that I use to apply different effects to the image by ColorAdjust. When I get the image from ImageChanger, the ColorAdjust changes aren't applied and the result is identical to the initial image. Is there any way to have these effects applied to the image itself rather than its ImageView so that changes are saved after extracting it?

```
    //applying effects to the image, they work properly when displaying imageChanger
    imageChanger.setBrightness(0.5);
    imageChanger.setContrast(2000D);
    Image image = imageChanger.getImage();
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    Group root = new Group(imageView);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 500));
    primaryStage.show(); //the image is identical to the one uploaded, no effects are applied
```

Comment: [mcve] please ... btw: there's rarely a good reason to extend a node (or any other class) when you can achieve the same by configuration

Comment: At least two options: (1) Manipulate the pixels of the image (using a `WritableImage`) rather than using an effect which only alters the rendering of the image; (2) Apply the effects and then take a snapshot of the `ImageView` (this option may have the potential to lose resolution, not sure).